# Cocos2d-x: should all the added children be removed MANUALLY when deallocing a CCNode object

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

The case is that I have a CCLayer created with cocosBuilder, and there are children added either programmatically or initially using the builder.
I am not sure if the children would be released correctly if I do not remove all of them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to remove them manually. Each node removes its children (empties the children array) when it deallocates.

Answer (score 0):

But I think we should remove them if we are adding them to the main game layer very frequently . As with time there will be lots of them waiting to be removed,which may increase memory usage.